# String operations vs Array operations in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, hash

I was solving the permutations of a string problem - Given two strings s1 and s2, write a function to return true if s2 contains the permutation of s1. In other words, one of the first string's permutations is the substring of the second string.

Example 1:
Input: s1 = "ab" s2 = "eidbaooo"
Output: True

Example 2: 
Input:s1= "ab" s2 = "eidboaoo"
Output: False

There is an array-based solution that stores the frequency of appearance of each letter in the substring and compares it every time with the given substring. This solution runs faster than mine. I don't understand why because I am performing addition of the letters of the string with an O(1) access time for arrays. Both solutions have sliding windows with the same limits. 
So, what is happening? Why is my solution slower?

```
    int findSum(char *string, int substringLength);
    bool checkInclusion(char * s1, char * s2){
        int substringLength = strlen(s1), substringSum = findSum(s1, substringLength);
        int stringLength = strlen(s2);
        if (stringLength < substringLength) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength - substringLength + 1; i++, s2++)
        {
           int currentSum = findSum(s2, substringLength);
           if (currentSum == substringSum) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int primes[26] = {2, 599, 23, 809, 11, 47, 3089, 853, 337, 1013, 13, 107, 787, 7, 383, 151, 1493, 
    947, 877, 2141, 431, 211, 59, 911, 23099, 307};
    int findSum(char *string, int substringLength)
    {
       int sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < substringLength; i++)
       {
           sum += primes[*(string + i) - 'a'];
       }
       return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking why this code is slower than another piece of code you're not showing?

Comment: Why would you expect the sums to be equal?  If the two strings were `ab` and `bca`, at which point in your `for` loop would the sum be equal?

Answer (score 2):

The array-based solution has a runtime of O(n) since it loops over each string once.  However, your solution has a runtime of O(n*m), where n and m are the lengths of the two strings.  Inside the `for` loop found in `checkInclusion`, you call `findSum` which has its own `for` loop.

You don't actually need to call `findSum` over and over again.  You can just subtract off the value of each character.

Comment: Wow, that really sped up my algorithm, thanks a lot! 
That was a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- Take a map of all the characters in `s1`
- Now take the map of characters in `s2` from index 0 to index `len(s1) — 1`
- If at this position the two maps are equal your job is done
- Otherwise for every new characters add it to `s2` map and remove the `i — len(s1)` character from the same map

**General Solution Template:**

In all such problem you start with a map of all character in the smaller string and a window of `len(s1)`. As you encounter a new character from `s2` you move the window by 1 that is you push both boundary by 1.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, we will follow these steps −

- create two vectors cnt1 and cnt2 of size 26
- for i in range 0 to s1

  - increase the value of cnt1[s1[i] – ‘a’] by 1
- j := 0 and required := size of s1
- for i in range 0 to size of s2

  - x := s2[I]
  - increase cnt2[x – ‘a’] by 1
  - if cnt1[x – ‘a’] and cnt2[x – ‘a’] <= cnt[x – ‘a’], then

    - decrease required by 1
  - while j <= i and cnt2[s2[j] – ‘a’] – 1 >= cnt1[s2[j] – ‘a’], do

    - decrease cnt2[s2[j] – ‘a’] by 1
    - increase j by 1
  - if i – j + 1 = size of s1 and required = 0, then return true
- return false.

#### SOLUTION IN C++:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
   bool checkInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
      vector <int> cnt1(26), cnt2(26);
      for(int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++)cnt1[s1[i] - 'a']++;
      int j = 0;
      int required = s1.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++){
         char x = s2[i];
         cnt2[x - 'a']++;
         if(cnt1[x - 'a'] && cnt2[x - 'a'] <= cnt1[x - 'a']) required--;
         while(j <= i && cnt2[s2[j] - 'a'] - 1 >= cnt1[s2[j] - 'a']){
            cnt2[s2[j] - 'a']--;
            j++;
         }
         if(i - j + 1 == s1.size() && required == 0){
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
};
```